# ERROR CS0102 Тип уже содержит определение для идентификатор, как это вообще возможно?

Tags: c#

Интересно я один с таким столкнулся?
В классе два разно именованных свойства, а компилятор считает, что это одно. И проект не собирается.

Что можно сделать? вариант переименовать сразу не подходит, так как много legacy завязаны на эти имена.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Дело в том, что компилятор C# при объявлении свойств неявно создает в коде 2 метода, get_назвсвойства и set_назвсвойства. Вот он и ругается. А у вас в коде есть свойство get_status, вот он и видит конфликт

Comment: Секрет в том, что под капотом свойство разворачивается в пару методов — для геттера, с префиксом get_ и для сеттера с префиксом set_

Comment: Но вообще, конечно, автор этого легаси — ССЗБ, во-первых, в C# мире принято использовать PascalCase для свойств, а во-вторых, что это за название такое для свойства set_status? Выход — переименовывать, можно, наверное, попробовать заменить свойства на поля, раз у вас там пустые геттеры/сеттеры, но лучше переименовывать

Comment: @АндрейNOP, AIAvenger, блин точно, запамятовал уже. спасибо большое!

Comment: Ну и вдогонку: `pl_inbound_plans` - тоже плохое название. Лучше сразу переименовать. PS: пользуйтесь анализаторами кода, они подскажут и исправят код.

Comment: snake_case не используют для имен свойств и классов, используют PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

В комментариях данного вопроса указали верное решение.

Необходимо писать код используя стиль PascalCase, это решение устранит ошибки в будущем.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]